# Bluetooth LE gatt continuously receive data

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I am working on an BLE android app that can continuously receive data from a sensor. I am using this open source [app](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/projects/how-to-communicate-with-a-custom-ble-using-an-android-app/)(1). This app can receive one set of data each time I click the button *Read Char*. Now, I want to modify it so that I can continuously receive data after I hit the button *Read Char*. Anyone know exactly where in the code I need to change in order to do what I need?

Also, I found another [app](https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/Android-nRF-UART)(2) that can receive data continuously after it connects to a sensor, I am trying to compare these two apps to see the difference, but did not turn out well.

The thing I notice is that I need to move 
 *mBluetoothLeService.readCustomCharacteristic();* from DeviceControlActivity.java in app(1) shown below to somewhere else because I think this line reads the value of the sensor.

```
   public void onClickRead(View v){
    if(mBluetoothLeService != null) {
        mBluetoothLeService.readCustomCharacteristic();
    }
}
```

In app(2) where they just continuously reads data after the connection, have a similar block of code inside a if statement in MainActivity.java, shown below:

```
            if (action.equals(UartService.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED)) {
             mService.enableTXNotification();
        }
```

since two apps are really similar I tried to move mBluetoothLeService.readCustomCharacteristic(); inside the elseif statement in DeviceControlActivity.java in app(1) shown below:

```
 if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
            mBluetoothLeService.readCustomCharacteristic(); 
        }
```

But this only read once and that's it.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Notifications is the way to go if you want to continuously receive data. I suggest you should read more on the basics of the GATT protocol.